# Swift Keychain cannot retrieve saved password from viewDidLoad for auto login feature

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

So in my app, when is user successfully login with username and password, the keychain will save the username and password. The implementation of the keychain is from this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Here is my login implementation where the keychain saves the username and password:

```
    func loginUser(from url: URL, with username: String, and password: String, completionHandler: @escaping (DrivetimeUserProfile?, DrivetimeAPIError.LoginError?) -> Void) { 

        let request = makeLoginRequest(url: url, with: username, password: password)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else {
                completionHandler(nil, .EmptyData)
                return
            }

            do {
                let userProfile = try JSONDecoder().decode(DrivetimeUserProfile.self, from: data)
                completionHandler(userProfile, nil)
                self.accountName = username
                self.keychainItem = KeychainPasswordItem(service: KeychainConfiguration.serviceName, account: username, accessGroup: KeychainConfiguration.accessGroup)
                try self.keychainItem?.savePassword(password)

            } catch {
                completionHandler(nil, .CannotDecodeJson)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Then, in my `loginViewController`, when the `loginButton` is tapped, it calls the `loginUser` like so:

```
@IBAction func onLoginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = URL(string: BASE_URL)!

    if !isUsernameAndPasswordIsFilled() {
        let alert = makeAlertDialogue(with: "Incomplete Information", description: "Please make you enter both username and password")
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    client.loginUser(from: url, with: userNameTextField.text!, and: passwordTextField.text!) { [weak self] (userProfile, error)  in

        self?.performUIUpdate {
            guard error == nil else {
                self?.handleLoginError(error: error)
                return
            }
            self?.userProfile = userProfile
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainTabBarController", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I try to access the savedPassword, it retrieves `nil`. I did some debugging and I am sure it is saving it in the keychain. I even create a separate project to proof to myself that the sample code from apple is indeed working. Could it be that fact that I am saving the password from a background thread and I am access the keychain in the main thread in my `loginViewController`?

Thanks!

**Update**

Here is the code accessing the keychain in the `loginViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    print(try! client.keychainItem?.readPassword())

}
```

Comment: where is your code for retrieve the keychain password

Comment: Please see update, but basically I'm trying to access it and printing the password out

Answer (score 0):

I just install example project from your link and had tested work well.
I assume you config KeychainPasswordItem class correct.
In your code i see a username, You can check username which is correct with your password or not.

```
if let accountName = accountName {
   do {
       let passwordItem = KeychainPasswordItem(service:KeychainConfiguration.serviceName, account: accountName, accessGroup: KeychainConfiguration.accessGroup)  
       accountNameField.text = passwordItem.account
       passwordField.text = try passwordItem.readPassword()
   }
   catch {
       fatalError("Error reading password from keychain - \(error)")
   }
}
```